# Amazon EC2 gui access?

Tags: amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am running a basic micro instance on Amazon EC2. I am wondering if it is possible to run some remote GUI to work in the system as root?

Comment: Why? It's a server. There is no GUI.

Comment: Convenience, I prefer using GUI rather than command line.

Comment: Funny. For me not having a GUI is the convenience.

Comment: Your reliance on a GUI will severely imped your ability to configure the instance.

Comment: Not to mention pointless load on the server.

Comment: Umm - for developers required to build applications, there are plenty of good reasons to want to enable a GUI on an EC2 instance.

Comment: Why cant people just answer the question and stop giving their personal opinions unless asked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking for file system access you can use something like Midnight Commander which you should be able to install via yum or apt depending on which distro you're running.

http://www.trembath.co.za/mctutorial.html

If you're looking for more functionality - such as actually configuring the server, creating accounts, working with the firewall, etc, you could look at something like Webmin.

http://www.webmin.com/

Lastly, if you want a full-blown remote desktop, you can install a desktop environment on your server (KDE, Gnome, etc) and then connect to it remotely using something like NoMachine.

http://www.nomachine.com/

I hope that one of those addresses your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'some remote GUI', what did you have in mind?  You can use VNC,for example http://blog.gobansaor.com/2008/06/11/nx-rather-than-vnc-for-ec2-desktop/ or
http://www.synergycode.com/services/oracle-on-amazon-ec2/item/set-up-vnc-and-remote-desktop-ec2

Comment: I mean that I can connect to the server using command line, and then operate it the same way, whereas I'd like to have some tool on my computer that would allow me to connect to the server in some way and then let me operate it in a GUI window, rather than terminal. Sort of like what Norton Commander or early Windows was to DOS - it works on top of the command line, only I`d obviously need something remote.

Comment: So, did you look at the URLs I posted?

Comment: dead link rot...

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a gui, go with [webmin](http://webmin.com)

Comment: I think he's looking for a full Linux-on-the-desktop experience.

Comment: If this is the case he should just install the server-gui package and setup VNC, or use an ubuntu desktop AMI